# How could I evaluate $A = \int_0^1 \log\left(\theta^s(1-\theta)^{n-s}\right)p(\theta)d\theta$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, beta-distribution, integral

Suppose that I want to evaluate the following integral:

$$A = \int_0^1 \log\left(\theta^s(1-\theta)^{n-s}\right)p(\theta)d\theta,$$
where $p(\theta)\equiv$ Beta$(ws+1, w(n-s)+1)$ and $n$, $w$, and $s$ are known constants. How would I go about evaluating this integral analytically?

Comment: Help yourself out by simplifying the integral.  You will see it comes down to integrating $\log\theta(\theta^{\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta-1})$ from $0$ to $1.$  That's the derivative of $B(\alpha,\beta)$ with respect to $\alpha.$ Expressing $B$ in terms of $\Gamma$ functions gives the result in terms of $\Gamma$ and its derivative or, equivalently, in terms of $\Gamma$ and the Polygamma function $\psi.$

Comment: Multiply that with $w/w$ and you will notice that its the definition of negative entropy. and the solution is on the wikipedia page

Comment: @onyambu By negative entropy, do you mean negentropy or  "-"entropy? I appreciate the connection that you're making here. In statistics, is there a typical route to solving negative entropy? From the "Information Theory" subsection of the "Entropy" wiki page, it seems that  the denominator in the $w/w$ is not part of the negative entropy definition, so that would still need to be accounted for, correct?

Comment: i mean `-H(x)`: Note that $A = \frac{w}{w}A \propto -\frac{1}{w}H(\theta)$ where $\theta$ follows the beta distribution you mentioned above. And $H(\theta)$ is given in the wikipedia page. Note that there are constants left out. You can include them to make your work simple

Comment: @onyambu I see now. That makes a lot more sense. Thank you! It appears that $H(\theta)$ is the differential entropy defined on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Differential_entropy. I'm not sure that I see the solution you found, though. I looked through the generic Entropy wiki page and the linked wiki page and only found various perspectives and definitions.

Comment: well yes its the differential entropy. Do you not see the relationship?

Comment: @onyambu I see the relationship now. It's great to put a name to this integral, and I'm having a fun time exploring entropy and this differential entropy. However, I'm not seeing the solution to $H(\theta)$ that you mentioned earlier. If a generic solution doesn't exist, that is fine. I'm just wondering if you know of a generic solution and can point me to it.

Comment: on wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution go to the right column  you will find the vpdf, cdf, mean, median mode, variance etc. Look for entropy

Comment: @onyambu Oh, I see what you mean now. Well, thank you so much, onyambu. You taught me a lot of cool things today. I'll be looking into information theory a bit more this weekend. I appreciate you!

Comment: @onyambu I added an answer given your help. I just have one question: is there a way to recover the normalizing constant for $A$? In the event that the normalizing constant is important, I'd like to be able to recover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired by @onyambu's comments and guidance.

First, let's simplify the expression for $A$:
$$A = \int_0^1 \log\left(\theta^s(1-\theta)^{n-s}\right)p(\theta)d\theta,$$
where $$p(\theta)=Beta(\alpha=ws+1, \beta=w(n-s) + 1)).$$
Then, if we multiply $A$ by $w/w$, we get
$$A=\frac{1}{w}\int_0^1\log\left(\theta^{ws}(1-\theta)^{w(n-s)}\right)p(\theta)d\theta.$$
Finally, let's add and subtract $\log(c)$, where $c$ is the normalizing constant for $p(\theta)$:
$$A=\frac{1}{w}\int_0^1\log\left(\theta^{ws}(1-\theta)^{w(n-s)}\right)p(\theta)d\theta +\log(c) - \log(c)\\
= \frac{1}{w}\int_0^1\log\left(\theta^{ws}(1-\theta)^{w(n-s)}\right)p(\theta)d\theta +\int_0^1 \log(c)p(\theta)d\theta - \log(c)\\
= \frac{1}{w}\int_0^1\left[\log(c) + \log\left(\theta^{ws}(1-\theta)^{w(n-s)}\right)\right]p(\theta)d\theta - \log(c)\\
=\frac{1}{w}\int_0^1\log\left(c\theta^{ws}(1-\theta)^{w(n-s)}\right)p(\theta)d\theta - \log(c)
$$

The above integral is equivalent to negative entropy, so
$$A=-\frac{1}{w}H(\theta) - \log(c),$$
where $$H(\theta)=\alpha + \log(\beta\Gamma(\alpha))-(1+\alpha)\psi(\alpha)$$ is the entropy for $p(\theta)$.

Comment: Note that the equations are missing the constants. ie $p(\theta)$ is missing the constant $\frac{1}{\mathcal{B}eta(\alpha, \beta)}$ and the log part is also missing the constant. Thats why I wrote its proportional to the entropy and not equivalent

Comment: @onyambu I streamlined my problem statement and updated my answer. Does everything look good to you now?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, because it merely quotes an answer: it doesn't "evaluate it analytically," as you have asked.

Comment: @whuber I get that I used the functional form for $H(\theta)$. Your original comment is more in-line with what I originally wanted. However, I wanted to explore the entropy idea a bit more.

Comment: @whuber If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it for sake of completeness :)

Comment: While youve added the log c, you are missing the C part of $p(\theta)$

Comment: @onyambu I rephrased the question to simplify things. So, I believe that constant is accounted for now.

Comment: Well then. As noted by whuber, i just couldn't add this as it is not a direct integración.